# Child controls flicker during resize of TCustomControl descendant

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

For long time I used descendant of `TCustomPanel` class, called MyContainer, in my application. Typical container for other visual controls I can say. And it was fine. One day I realized that I don't use panel functionality at all so I can derive MyContainer directly from `TCustomControl`.

After doing so I experience horrible flickering for child controls (e.g. aligned TMemo) when MyContainer is being resized using mouse. It is just horrible - it looks like entire TMemo is disappering for a moment so I can see the background. MyContainer paints itself fine - it is a problem only with child controls.

It was not happening when MyContainer was derived from TCustomPanel. What I am missing and where? Child control is double buffered and MyContainer too. I use Delphi 7 Personal Edition, so I don't have VCL source and so I am unable to compare TCustomPanel with TCustomControl implementation. Handling `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` and `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` messages (to enable/disable child align) does not help.

I believe my problem is connected with erasing control background. As part of my "migration" to TCustomControl I added the following code to Paint method:

```
Canvas.Font.Assign(Font);
Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
PatBlt(Canvas.Handle, Canvas.ClipRect.Left, Canvas.ClipRect.Top, Canvas.ClipRect.Right, Canvas.ClipRect.Bottom, PATCOPY);
```

Without this code, child control does not flicker anymore but painting of parent control is ruined.

Comment: "*I don't have VCL source*" - why not? It has been included in every Delphi release since the dawn of time.  Without seeing your actual code, we can't tell you what you are (or are not) doing wrong.

Comment: @Remy I can only guess it's either a cracked or trial version of Delphi 7.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Yes re trial:  Istr (but it was a long time ago) that in the D5/D7 era, there were versions distributed on magazine front covers in the UK at least that were w/o source.

Comment: Perhaps your code is to blame. We can't see it. [mcve] please.

Comment: The Starter SKU does not come with source code, AFAIK.

Comment: And not all SKUs did come with the VCL sources in the past either. Turbo and Standard SKUs did not have them. So not all Delphi releases did have them. Only Pro and above.

Comment: I use Delphi 7 Personal Edition

Comment: Just curious as to why anyone would think that a cracked version would not come with everything that the legit version of that thing would not come with and focus on picking that apart rather than helping the OP.  From the info in the question I suspected what the problem was.  A couple of minutes later I had confirmed with a repro case.  A couple of minutes after that I had a solution.  It was a legit question with sufficient information to quickly identify the problem and reach a solution.  The question absolutely did **not** deserve a downvote imho.

Comment: +Deltics Yes it does. And it should be closed because there is no [mcve]. This isn't a game of 20 questions. Questions are required to specify the problem precisely.

Comment: @David Heffernan - I don't understand your definition of "precisely" because this question was demonstrably more than adequately precise.  Some people seem to have an obsession (bordering on the fetishistic) with linking to the MCVE topic and beating people up for not providing code to spoon feed a repro case before deigning to even bother to try to help.  It's simply not *always* necessary.  Where it is, then fair enough, but where there is enough information to *create* a MCVE almost as quickly as one could be copy/pasted (as in this case) insisting on one is just pointlessly pedantic.

Comment: @deltics Not so. Countless times one attempts to recreate the behaviour and then finds that it cannot easily be done. Because there is some missing nuance. Further the onus is on the asker to invest this time for the benefit of all readers. Finally the act of preparing the MCVE often leads the asker to a solution. Anyway, if as you say it really is trivial to reproduce this behaviour then why is it onerous for the asker to do so? My experience when asking is that the more time invested to ask, the better the response.

Comment: @David - Ever hear of "the exception that proves the rule" ?  I do not think it helpful to knee-jerk demand an MCVE before even considering whether one is needed.  If your assertion were correct then the *only* questions with answers on SO would be those with MCVE's.  That is *patently* not the case and your position is shown to be simply one of smug high-handedness, not practical concern.  Where an MCVE is *required* then of course it is right to insist on one, but that does *not* mean it is *always* necessary.  All your points may be valid w.r.t other questions, but not this one.  /end

Comment: @Deltics You know enough about statistics to know that this one example proves nothing. One time in three (wild estimate) with this kind of question, the asker would have come back and said, oh, it turns out there was more to my program that I didn't tell you about. That's why we should always have an MCVE for a question like this. In my view your attitude simply encourages askers to be lazy. I fundamentally disagree with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between **TCustomPanel** and **TCustomControl** that affects this behaviour is that **TCustomPanel** adds the **csAcceptControls** style to the **ControlStyle** in the constructor.  This in turn then affects the behaviour in the **TWinControl** base class, which adds the **WS_CLIPCHILDREN** style to the window for the controls with that style set.

So, you can achieve the same result in one of two ways:

1. Override the **constructor** and add the **csAcceptsControls** to the **ControlStyle** of your container control

OR

2. Override **CreateParams** and directly add the **WS_CLIPCHILDREN** flag to the window **Style** of your container control

### The Code

**Option 1:**

```
constructor TMyContainer.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
end;
```

Note that this will mean that your container control can now accept controls dropped on it at *design-time*.  Even without this **ControlStyle** you can add controls to a container at run-time by setting the **Parent** property.

**Option 2:**

```
procedure TMyContainer.CreateParams(var aParams: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  aParams.Style := aParams.Style or WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
end;
```

This achieves the specific change in painting behaviour you are after but without affecting the ability of the control to accept controls at design-time.

Comment: Option 2 so adding WS_CLIPCHILDREN to params did the trick. Thanks!